# Calculate Profitability in DAX (Power BI)

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the following dataset:

[image]

The extrato_fi table has a list of companies referenced by CNPJ_FUNDO and it's name DENOM_SOCIAL. The Informes Diários table has the date (dd/MM/yyyy) and the VL_TOTAL which means the amount of money the company have in that day.

So, I'd like to calculate the profitability in % and the formula is:

- Sum of VL_TOTAL of all dates / VL_TOTAL of the first date
- It must be possible to filter by date and/or CNPJ_FUNDO in order to know the profitability of a companies or companies in any date or in an interval of dates (See the filters image below. Ano means Year, Mês means Month)
- It must be possible to drill down by year, month or day in any table or graph

[image: filters]

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Add some dummy date and desired output.

Comment: first date always the minimum date of entire data? or minimum date from the date range selector (01-01-2005) from the filter?